# how can I pass a dataset to an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object  called arr and I want to add a dataset to it , here is my code so far .

```
  arr = { date:'222222' } 

  lines = [
      { line1:'line1' , name:'paul' } ,
      { line2:'line2' , name:'john' } ,
      ]

  arr.push( lines )
```

I want to send arr to handlebars but need the lines adding to arr .

I want to end up with

```
      arr = { date : '222222' ,
              lines: [   
                { line1:'line1' , name:'paul' } ,
                { line2:'line2' , name:'john' } 
                ],
               more etc: 'more vars' 
             }
```

but using push just isn't doing it, can anyone tell me what Iam doing wrong , any help appreciated ! , thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    arr.lines =  [{ line1:'line1' , name:'paul' },{ line2:'line2' , name:'john' }]
```

Objects in JS are mutable so you can just dynamically assign new members to them.  You could also do;

```
arr.moreVars = 1234; 
arr.moreVars2 = ['hi', 'bye'];
```

Furthermore, push relates to arrays.  you're operating on an object literal which is why push isn't working.  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp

One more comment here, since you are operating on an object literal, you're likely to confuse yourself (or other people who have to maintain your code) by naming it 'arr'.  Its good practice to name your variables so that their names describe what they are.  Take the following example:

```
function Person(name, age){
this.myName = name; 
this.myAge = age;
}

var dog = new Person('bob', 31);
```

later on in the code, you're likely to try and do things related to dogs to this variable.